# What's the right way to display system sound volume in conky?

Tags: conky

What's the right way of displaying system sound volume in conky ? I don't have `/dev/mixer` file, and without an external command, is it possible ?

Conky 1.9.0

Answer (score 3):

I use `${exec amixer -c 0 get Master | grep Mono:}`.

Comment: This, of course, assumes that you use ALSA (which is quite possibly a good guess).

Comment: to retain only the percentage and retain it only when it's unmuted: ${exec amixer -c 0 get Master | grep Mono: | grep -v off | grep -oP '\d+%'}

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solution(s) and neither worked for me, I was able to get it working with a variation:

```
${exec amixer get Master | grep -o -P -m1 "[0-9][0-9](?=\%\])"}
```

This works on conky 1.12 with amixer version 1.2.8, however.